# Impose character between repeated characters

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, patterns

Given a string of characters `,,a,,,b,,,,` I want to impose the character `-` at the beginning, if no character is preceded comma, and between every comma that has no character. Meaning the result is `-,-,a,-,-,b,-,-,-,-`. Now, I already tried:

```
echo ",,a,,,b,,,," | sed 's/,/,-/g' | sed 's/-\([^,]\)/\1/g' | sed 's/^,/-&/g'
```

resulting in: `-,-,a,-,-,b,-,-,-,-`

But the problem is, invoking sed 3 times is inefficient in *very long iterations*. Is there a way to do this with sed, probably using **regex**, or any other tool **invoking it once**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One* way to do it in `sed` would be to use a loop:

```
$ echo ",,a,,,b,,,," | sed ':a; s/\(^\|,\)\(,\|$\)/\1-\2/; ta'
-,-,a,-,-,b,-,-,-,-
```

If your version supports extended regular expressions you can simplify it to a more readable

```
sed -E ':a; s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1-\2/; ta'
```

---

An alternate way to do it in `perl`, splitting into comma-separated fields and then mapping empty fields to hyphens:

```
perl -anle 'print join ",", map { $_ ? $_ : "-" } split(",", $_, -1)'
```

(The additional `-1` argument to the `split` forces trailing empty fields to be included).

Answer (score 3):

```
(echo ,,a,,,b,,,,; echo a,,b) | perl -pe 's/(^|,)\K(?=(,|$))/-/g' 
-,-,a,-,-,b,-,-,-,-
a,-,b
```

I guess I should learn `sed` one of these years.

Comment: Try [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html) one of these years.  ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But when I input **'a,,a,,,b,,,,'** it gives **'-a,-,a,-,-,b,-,-,-,-'**. How do I avoid inputting **-** when there is a letter before the first **,**?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ",,a,,,b,,,," |
  awk -v 'FS=,' -v 'OFS=,' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sub(/^$/,"-",$i); print};'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo ',,a,,,b,,,,' | sed 's/\(\([^,]\+,\)*\),/\1-,/g; s/\(^\|,\)$/\1-/'
-,-,a,-,-,b,-,-,-,-
```

The second expression (the `s/\(^\|,\)$/\1-/`) is necessary only because `sed` seems to stop matching when it has reached the end of the pattern space, even though it could still match a `$` if the only expression were `s/\(\([^,]\+,\)*\)\(,\|$\)/\1-\3/g`.

Of course, `sed -E` makes it a bit more readable, but otherwise equivalent:

```
sed -E 's/(([^,]+,)*),/\1-,/g; s/(^|,)$/\1-/'
```